# compliment of {a^n b^n c^n} in TOC

Tags: automata

As we know the language `{a^n b^n c^n}` is not CFL for `sigma={a,b,c}`, then I am eager to know its complement. Will it be cfl ? 
Please let me know where I am wrong. According to me the compliment should be `{a^i b^j c^k | i!=j or j != k}` union `(a+b+c)*cba(a+b+c)*`.

Answer (score 1):

The complement of the language {a^nb^nc^n} is a CFL. We can write a CFG for this language.

Informally it is language a^ib^jc* + a^ib*c^j + a*b^ic^j + .*ba.* + .*cb.* + .*ca.*, where i!= j .